# is there a way to replicate the doppler effect (shift)?

Tags: sound-effects

I was wondering if there is a way to imitate how the doppler effect or shift sounds. The specific way I'm planning to use it will be for a build up using a bass type synth, but that may be irrelevant. I thought about maybe panning with some volume automation, but my attempts weren't even close to correct.

This gif will help

[image: dop yo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Waves plugins have this: http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=244

Ive used it a few times and it sounds ok but it is not free however.

Also Cakewalk sell this: http://www.store.cakewalk.com/b2cus/ProductInfo.aspx?productid=36-CWSF3.31-10E and it has a doppler as part of the surround package.

Some free ones:

http://freemusicsoftware.org/category/free-vst-effects-2/doppler

http://www.vst4free.com/free_vst.php?plugin=ADopplerEn&id=517

http://laut8leise.de/_l8l/asa.html (called "away" but you may need to change the file extension to .iso for it to work in windows - http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/toast)

http://www.kvraudio.com/product/spacestation_by_oli_larkin - seems to be unavailable but his website is still up http://www.olilarkin.co.uk/

A basic replication could probably be achieved however with some pitch and volume automation.

Taken from : http://forum.cockos.com/archive/index.php/t-106794.html

"Use pitch-shift and automate the envelope to have a tangential profile. Ie start with the sound pitched up a couple of semitones and over the period of time gradually start to drop the pitch, have the envelope slope at its steepest as it crosses pitch neutral, and then gradually bottom the slope out at 2 semitones pitched dowm. 2 semitones is a starting point, depends on relative velocities...

If you follow a tangential shape for the pitch envelope, this will mimic the rate of change of source relative velocity and the resultant pitch change experienced by an observer being passed by a constant velocity sound source.

The maths isn't that complicated if you had real numbers to play with, but it should follow a tangent function of variable positive and negative start and end pitches, with a zero-crossing angle dependent on how close you would be to the moving object (nearly vertical for fast and close, more gentle for slower or further away).

Everything else is level, noise and timbre -add some rumble, white noise and filters and and volume envelope the lot of them ;)

Have fun! :D
"

Comment: thats pretty sweet looking. but it is not free is it?

Comment: Nope, unfortunalty not. Are you looking for a free one? I did find something called spacestation but looks like its no longer available (however im sure some google searches will yield some results) http://www.kvraudio.com/product/spacestation_by_oli_larkin

Comment: I can't upvote it because I used all my upvotes for the day apparently, so I will tomorrow!

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum No worries dude. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Simple way and free way to "suggest" a Doppler effect.

The two most significant factors that get this effect are point source position changing and a slight pitch shift.

These can easily be done by panning the sound and dropping the pitch at the appropriate time--use you ears to determine the best mix.

Yes, you can make this more sophisticated by adding slight changes of reverberation or sound reflection to convey how the sound would change near/far, also slight changes to the spectra by adding and subtracting hi and low end as per how higher frequencies will roll off as they gain distance, while lower frequencies are not as clearly muted. Additionally adding more background or subtracting background information, noise, and so on.

Here is a wiki on all the factors involved with near/far perception of sound:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization